# Unable to Call another fxml page on button click event

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am Trying to come up with simple tool where I want to Call another fxml page on a button click from present fxml page. 
My Main Java class is designed as follows:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application 
{

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    try {

        TitledPane page = (TitledPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("NewTest.fxml"));
         Scene scene = new Scene(page);
        stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle("Welome Page");
            stage.show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(Main.class, (java.lang.String[])null);
}}
```

and Controller Class is designed as :

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class SimpleController implements Initializable 
{

   @FXML //  fx:id="loginbtn"
   private Button loginbtn; // Value injected by FXMLLoader


   @Override // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when
                 initialization is complete
   public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {
    assert loginbtn != null : "fx:id=\"myButton\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'simple.fxml'.";

    // initialize your logic here: all @FXML variables will have been injected
    loginbtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
             Stage stage; 
             Parent root;
             if(event.getSource()==loginbtn){
                //get reference to the button's stage         
                stage=(Stage) loginbtn.getScene().getWindow();
                //load up OTHER FXML document
                try{
                    TitledPane page =(TitledPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("secondPage.fxml"));
                }catch(Exception e)
                {e.printStackTrace();}
              }
        }
    });
}
}
```

And the Fxml Page is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

 <TitledPane text="Welcome to the Vacation Planner" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <content>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="330.0" prefWidth="497.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="52.0" prefHeight="25.0"  prefWidth="189.0" text="User Name">
              <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
              </font>
             </Label>
             <TextArea layoutX="53.0" layoutY="106.0" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="391.0" />
                <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="165.0" text="Password">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="24.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Button fx:id="loginbtn" layoutX="114.0" layoutY="262.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Login">
           <font>
              <Font size="18.0" />
           </font>
        </Button>
        <Button fx:id="exitbtn" layoutX="271.0" layoutY="262.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Exit">
           <font>
              <Font size="18.0" />
           </font>
           </Button>
           <PasswordField layoutX="53.0" layoutY="207.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="391.0" />
         </children>
        </AnchorPane>
       </content>
      </TitledPane>
```

When I am clicking on the button Login it is not opening the Second xml page that I am trying to open on button click.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You load the `Node`s and then do nothing with it.

You need to add them to the existing scene or replace that scene:

```
try{
    TitledPane page =(TitledPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("secondPage.fxml"));
    Scene newScene = new Scene(page);
    stage.setScene(newScene);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Furthermore you haven't associated the controller with the fxml. Use e.g. the `fx:controller` attribute with the fully qualified class name of the controller class at the root of the fxml to do this:

```xml
<TitledPane text="Welcome to the Vacation Planner" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="my.package.SimpleController">
```

Where `my.package` would be the package containing the controller.

Comment: Hi , I tried to us the code that you have suggested still it is not opening the fxml page that I am trying to open.

Comment: @priya89 I didn't see you didn't use the controller class anywhere; Edited the answer now... BTW: I assume the controller compiles instead of resulting in a compile time exception, since `initialization is complete` isn't inside comments